# XML parsing fails in Ruby with standalone="yes" attribute (libxml-ruby 2.3.3 gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, libxml2

When I run the following Ruby code:

```
xml_str = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><project name=\"ProjectA\"/>"

parser = XML::Reader.string(xml_str, :encoding => XML::Encoding::UTF_8,
                                :options => ( XML::Parser::Options::NOENT | XML::Parser::Options::NOBLANKS))
parser.read
```

It throws an exception:

```
Fatal error: Extra content at the end of the document at :1.
LibXML::XML::Error: Fatal error: Extra content at the end of the document at :1.
from (irb):55:in `read'
from (irb):55
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Can anybody tell why this code fails?

Note: If I either remove `standalone=\"yes\"` or change the XML string to have a separate end element instead of the self-closing root tag, the exception goes away.

Comment: I prefer `nokogiri` over `libxml-ruby` and `nokogiri` parses this perfectly. Maybe give that a shot

Comment: I can’t reproduce this, your code doesn’t give an error for me.